# Can I change specify the location of a python generated file ad-hoc from terminal?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a piece of code that generates a .dat and .hdf5 file, saving them to the directory from which the generation code is run. I was wondering if there is a way to specify the save path of those two files from the command line in a similar way to how the following works, for example:

```
h5dump example.hdf5 > tmp.txt
```

In an ideal world, I would like something like the following:

```
python python_code.py > /PATH/TO/DESIRED/DIRECTORY/
```

Where the two files (.dat and .hdf5) will be saved. Of course I could hardcode the /PATH/TO/DESIRED/DIRECTORY/ but I will be making small changes to python_code.py to generate different output files and it would be handy to be able to quickly specify their saved locations to keep the different runs separate.

Comment: Why not pass it as an *argument* to the code; `python python_code.py /path/to/dir`?

Comment: What you're describing is called *shell redirection* which is a feature of your shell for taking the output of a program and sending it somewhere else, such as writing it to a file. Any program you write that outputs something to *standard out* works this way. If you use `print()` for example, by default it prints to stdout and so can be redirected like this (stderr can be redirected as well). Of course, you can also write arbitrary binary data to stdout. But I would also suggest taking a filename as an *argument* instead, unless you expect to also be able to pipe to other programs.

Comment: as @jonrsharpe said - send it as argument and then you get it as `sys.argv[1]`. Eventually use module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to get more complex arguments. ie. `python python_code.py --input path1 --output path2 --format hd5f`

Answer (score 0):

If you run code without `>`

```
python python_code.py /PATH/TO/DESIRED/DIRECTORY/
```

then you get path in `sys.argv[1]`

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
   path = sys.argv[1]
else:
   path = '/default/path/'

print(path)
```

and now you can use this `path` to rest of code

---

If you don't have default path then you can print message and exit program

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
   path = sys.argv[1]
else:  
   print("You forgot path")
   exit(1)

print(path)
```

---

For more complext arguments like

```
python python_code.py --input path1 --output path2 --format hd5f

python python_code.py -i path1 -o path2 -f hd5f

python python_code.py --help
```

use module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input',  default='/default/input/path', help="path to input file [default: %(default)s]")
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', default='/default/output/path', help="path to output file [default: %(default)s]")
parser.add_argument('-f', '--format', default='hd5f', help="outputformat [default: %(default)s]")
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.input)
print(args.output)
print(args.format)
```